# Interesting Combinatorial Identities; e.g. $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2 = {2n\choose n}$

Tags: combinatorics

I came across the following combinatorial identity:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2 = {2n\choose n}$$

Here's the kind of proof which caught my interest:

$\sum_k {n \choose k}^2 = \sum_k {n \choose k}{n \choose n - k}$, and this represents the number of ways we might choose a committee of $n$ people out of a group of $2n$ people. On the other hand, ${2n \choose n}$ represents the same thing. So the result follows.

Now, I'm looking for some nice combinatorial identities which are, in spirit, similar to such an identity.

Thank you.

Comment: There's quite a lot of nice things here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient
including a proof of your identity

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: did you bother reading the question?

Comment: The Google search `"combinatorial argument" OR "combinatorial proof" site:math.stackexchange.com` will turn up many examples.

Comment: As an aside, letting $n=\dfrac12$ in the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity) you quoted, we get a formula for $\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a book called "Proofs that Really Count: The Art of Combinatorial Proof" by Arthur T. Benjamin and Jennifer J. Quinn, which might be of interest to you.

Comment: Also [the downloadable book "A-B"](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) on methods for automatically discovering and proving combinatorial identities by Wilf, et al.